# Don't throw an exception if xml deserialize failed

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

App1 serializes some class A to .xml file using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
Another App2 neesd to parse multiple xml files, and only process those that were serialized by App1 from Class A. 
The problem is that there's different .xml file (not created by App1 - just some xml) - I have an exception in this code:

```
// inside a loop
FullTestResult newResult = new FullTestResult();    
Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FullTestResult));
newResult = (FullTestResult)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
stream.Close();
```

I tried adding try-catch, but even if there's an exception when trying to parse unrelated xml - newResult is not null. Is there any simple way to just skip those files that can't be parsed by returning newResult=null or by some other means?

Comment: Why can't you wrap it into `try...catch` block and just skip if exception occured?

Comment: Using exceptions as a way to indicate control flow isn't a great idea. Do you have any way of determining which XML are of your type? Maybe a specific file name?